# Split and Merge MP4 video

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, video-encoding

I have a desktop application (mfc) in which now I have to implement split and merge of MP4 videos. I have searched a lot and found almost nothing online. Please help me with some hints on how to proceed and what to use. Splitting and merging should be done on timeline basis and not based on size. Code is in VC++

Can I achieve this with Windows Video Encoder? If yes, how to know about the exposed methods in WME?

Answer (score 1):

DirectShow (now part of Windows SDK) provides editing services (EDS) but I would suggest  ffmpeg (http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) as a better choice since it would support wider range of formats (e.g. H.264 - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390353(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).